# How do I set protection level for each package in VS Integration Services project?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I added an `Execute SQL Task` to my control flow.
I configured it to use a connection manager.

When I pressed `Build Query` I got an error saying `Login failed for user xxx`.
I checked the settings on my connection manager 100 times.
After googling a while I found that it could be because the `ProtectionLevel` is set to encrypt sensitive settings.

So in order to check if this was the thing causing my error, I had to change my ProtectionLevel to `DontSaveSensitive` instead. Ok, so I did this on project level. 
When I build I get error because `Package.dtsx has a different ProtectionLevel than the project.` So I need to change for the package as well. But I can't find the setting! It is not on the property page for the package, and I don't know where else to look.

Any suggestion?

Edit: See picture
[image: package]

Comment: ProtectionLevel is a package property.   I don't know why you're not seeing it on the property page.   It's there on mine.  If you're sure you're looking in the right place, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @TabAlleman please see edit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, you're looking in the wrong place.   : )

Click on the "Package.dtsx [Design]" tab.

Click in an empty space on the control flow.

If you don't see a list of properties (it's in the lower right corner by default) then pull down the "View" menu and click "Properties Window".

There you will see a FULL list of package properties, and ProtectionLevel will be one of them.

Right now you are looking at the external properties of the dtsx file.  Clicking inside the control flow exposes the internal properties of the package.